NGINX Next.js and WordPress in Subdirectory /resources - WordPress Permalink with 'Post name' not working
I have a server running a Next.js app and a WordPress site. The Next.js app is served on the root (/) path and runs on port 3000 with pm2. WordPress is installed in the /resources subdirectory located in /var/www/html/wordpress. My NGINX configuration for the server is as follows:
server {
  server_name example.app www.example.app;

  location /resources {
    alias /var/www/html/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }

 location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
 }

This works well when the WordPress permalinks are set to 'Plain', e.g., https://example.app/resources/?p=123. However, when I change the permalinks to 'Post name', e.g., https://example.app/resources/sample-post/, it starts routing to the Next.js app and I get a 500 error.
After some searching, I updated my NGINX configuration for WordPress to:
location /resources {
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  alias /var/www/html/wordpress;
  index index.php index.html;

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
 }

Now, the issue I'm facing is that the URL https://example.app/resources/sample-post/ returns a file not found error, and none of the WordPress permalinks work anymore.
What I need help with:
How can I get WordPress permalinks with 'Post name' to work under the /resources path without interfering with my Next.js routes on /?
Is there a better way to configure NGINX to handle both Next.js and WordPress properly in this setup?
Any advice or insight would be greatly appreciated!

After struggling with this issue for several days and trying various solutions from Copilot and ChatGPT without success, I finally found a solution through a Reddit post and a blog it referenced.
The issue was that WordPress permalinks under /resources weren't being correctly routed to WordPress, especially when using the 'Post name' structure. The root cause was that NGINX wasn't handling nested permalinks properly, causing conflicts with my Next.js routes.
Here’s the NGINX configuration that finally worked for me:
location /resources {
    alias /var/www/html/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html;
    
    # Try files and redirect to @nested if the file isn't found
    try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

    # PHP processing for WordPress
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

# Handle nested permalinks for WordPress
location @nested {
    rewrite /resources/(.*)$ /resources/index.php?/$1 last;
}

Explanation:

try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

This tries to serve the requested file or directory and, if not found, sends the request to a named location (@nested).

@nested location

The rewrite rule here ensures that requests like /resources/sample-post/ are routed to /resources/index.php, allowing WordPress to handle permalinks correctly.
